# Easiest way to fill array with an object in JavaScript without coding a loop?

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following object:

```
var obj = { foo: 'bar' };
```

I want to add this object to an array X amount of times so the result is:

```
[{ foo: 'bar' }, { foo: 'bar'}, ... , { foo: 'bar'}]
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without explicitly coding a loop?

Comment: is `fiveHundredChars` the array you want to insert the object into?

Comment: Is this just in an attempt to make the code look more concise? Any solution you come up with is likely to have a loop-like implementation in the background, so there won't be any difference in theoretical or practical efficiency. If you're doing this more than once in your code you can just define a function for it so you don't repeat the loop.

Comment: @nbrooks, yes you're correct regarding code looking more concise.

Comment: *Suppose* you could do the same as the trick with the string (often used to generate padding).. Then since it would be an object, you would have filled your array with 500 references to *the same* object. Is this your intention? *edit* Why did you remove that example with the string?

Comment: why don't you build a function? and what do you want exactly (the benefit)?

Comment: @GitaarLAB - the string example outputs a string, not an array, which was confusing the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var filled = Array.apply(null, Array(501)).map(function() { return {"foo":"bar"} });
```

Comment: Plot twist: this is still a loop

Comment: Sad thing is the OP is not looking to not loop. What the OP wants is to try to make the code look "cleaner" which is reality means making it more confusing to read. Now is this slower over a while loop? I am too lazy to jsperf it.

Comment: @epascarello yeah, this is definitly a good method, but OP is trying to programmatically kill himself.

Answer (score 11):

There is a way: manually. Any programmatic solution will indeed use a loop here, which, if you wish to maintain your sanity -- use it.

Comment: I was thinking about saying that.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using [`.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

```
const someArray = ['test']; // Any other data you may have
const resultingArray = new Array(100).fill({ foo: 'bar' }).concat(someArray);
```

Set 100 to whatever number you need, `concat` any extra data after (or before if needed)

As @isvforall pointed out this isn't a deep copy and is done via reference so changing any of the elements in the array would affect all of the others which reference the same object. Best used if your values are primitives.

Comment: `Array.fill` doesn't do a deep copy. All references to the same object. If you change one object the everyone will be the same

Comment: @isvforall fair enough, and good catch, not sure it's worth a downvote since the user never said they would be modifying the array or object however it is worth noting for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I think epascarello's answer is already a winner, and I +1'd it, but here's another approach just for kicks, using your `Array.join()` trick along with `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`.

Verbose:

```
var obj = { foo: 'bar' };
var objJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
var list = new Array(501).join(objJSON + ',')
var trimmedList = list.substr(0, list.length - 1); // getting rid of that last comma
var arrayJSON = '[' + trimmedList + ']';
var array = JSON.parse(arrayJSON);
console.log(array);
```

Compact:

```
var list = new Array(501).join(JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar' }) + ',')
var array = JSON.parse('[' + list.substr(0, list.length - 1) + ']');
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Still a plot twist: yet another loop

Comment: +1 for originality and thinking outside the box (and proving in the process the OP is better of with less work and clearer code in the form of a loop (tucked away in a function to maintain readability in his main routine)).

Comment: @GitaarLAB http://demotivators.despair.com/demotivational/mistakesdemotivator.jpg - My true calling? :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* don't want a loop you can use recursion.

```
function objFillArray(obj, count) {
    let ret = [];
    return notALoop();
    function notALoop() {
        ret.push(obj);
        if( --count ) return notALoop();
        return ret;
    }
}
```

this will keep calling notALoop `count` number of times adding the object to the returned array.

Answer (score 1):

Using recursion and `concat` function

```
var obj = { foo: 'bar' };

var result = (function fill(a, len) {
    return a.length == len ? a : fill(a.concat(obj), len);
})([], 10);
```

```js
var obj = { foo: 'bar' };

var result = (function fill(a, len) {
    return a.length == len ? a : fill(a.concat(obj), len);
})([], 10);

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback function in [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) can be used to ensure each element of the array is a different reference.

```js
const arr = Array.from({length: 5}, _=>({foo: 'bar'}));
console.log(arr);
```

If all elements are meant to be the same reference, directly use [`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill).

```js
const arr = Array(5).fill({foo: 'bar'});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `.push()` function to assign value to an array.

```
    yourarray.push(yourobject);
               |
               |
               |
               V
    fiveHundredChars.push(obj);
```

Comment: so.. you type this 500 times? Ok, it's not a loop, but you must be joking right? `:)`

Comment: I don't get what Andrew's meant -_-

Comment: So why did you post an answer?

Comment: I think `loop` is the efficient way to do it.